# Restart aplication with some proprieties from the previous

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application in which I want to put a restart button, but when it restarts I want it to automatically reconnect with my bluetooth device. here's my code:

```
// Restart app
void gui::restartapp()
{
    int index_combo;

    index_combo= ui->devices_infile->currentIndex();

    QProcess::startDetached(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
    QCoreApplication::exit()

    char *dest;
    dest = addr_infile[index_combo];

    sock = linkup_directmain(dest, sock);

    if (sock != 0 && sock >0)
    {
        ui->console_1->setText("Connected to:");
        ui->console_2->setText(name_infile[index_combo]);
    }

    else if (sock == -1)
    {
        ui->console_1->setText("Error connecting");
        ui->console_2->setText("Check device status");
    }
}
```

but it only restarts. any idea?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

I got it to work. I'll publish it later in case someone else needs it.

Comment: what does 'exit(12);' do?

Comment: sorry. its supposed to be 0. my bad.

Comment: so the code after 'exit(0);' never gets executed?

Comment: well, it's that code which exits the application. the number in it is only what the application will return.

Comment: sure, but it will terminate the program right there, won't it, so the code following it will never run?

Comment: I guess that's the problem.

Comment: You can use QSettings to store the data for your current session, and re-read it on restart.

Comment: So did you mean to call QCoreApplication::exit() and called the stdlib version instead?

Comment: yes, I've replaced that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Restart app
void gui::restartapp()
{
    close_s(sock);

    last_session = true;

    settings.setValue("deviceid", ui->devices_infile->currentIndex());
    settings.setValue("lastsession", last_session);

    QProcess::startDetached(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
    QCoreApplication::exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`QCoreApplication::exit()` only tells the app to quit. The code after `exit()` is executed in the same application instance as the `restartapp()` was called. The other instance of the app is simply started. 
You should store your settings somewhere and then load them on application start.

Comment: I got it to work. I'll publish it later in case someone else needs it.